# Beginner Facebook Access Token Questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to better understand Facebook Access tokens. I have a canvas web app in a sandbox. I have used the GUI to say the app seeks permissions for various user fields. The user then sees these listed and clicks the blue Go To App button. (Currently only developers and testers).

My questions are around the Access tokens. I've used the Graph API explorer and the Access Token Tool. In the Access Token Tool - there are User and App tokens listed. What are these for?

A user must have a token to use an app - this token is generated when they click to use the app... can this expire? What is the purpose of an app access token? Is this to be used to view which users are subscribed to the app?

Any explanation or step through of the process of accepting and using an app on facebook would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Please read the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access token is similar to a password in a weaker notion.

Whenever a user tries to access to a resource, your app should authenticate the user. In this context, your app requets to access some or all user data, in return you are given an access token that expires in a short period of time. Something like 1 hour, then once the token expires you need to authenticate the user again. There are ways to extend expiration duration upto 2 months.

Facebook docs are pretty clear and concise about tokens, you can read through them, and depending on the language you are using, there are API's you can benefit from.

Overall pretty easy.

Comment: So if I install an app on facebook and allow it to see, say my photos, it has to re-seek permission to do this regularly?

Comment: no you do that once. You provide permissions for user data only once. But you need to ensure that user is authenticated through facebook, ths way facebook has more control over users and perhaps on your app too.

Comment: Ah I see the difference. Permissions happen once. Access tokens happen each time the 'permitted thing' is requested. Thanks for your help! What is the purpose of the App Access Token? since that does not involve a user (I think)?

Comment: That s involved when you need to push data to graph api. There was actions such as "read, watched" etc. That shows in activity feeds etc.